# Cloud Firestore: When should I use the data type Byte instead of the data type Text String?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

On the Firestore [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types) it lists the data type Bytes and Text String.

```
Data type   | Sort Order                | Notes
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Bytes       | Byte order                | Up to 1,048,487 bytes (1 MiB - 89 bytes). Only the first 1,500 bytes are considered by queries.
Text string | UTF-8 encoded byte order  | Up to 1,048,487 bytes (1 MiB - 89 bytes). Only the first 1,500 bytes of the UTF-8 representation are considered by queries.
```

I was wondering when it is optimal to use Bytes instead of Text String and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings are used when you have UTF-8 encoded characters in the data.  Bytes are used for any other binary data that is not a UTF-8 string, nor any other data type natively supported by Firestore.